# How to translate “Up for it”?

Tags: traduction, anglais, expressions-idiomatiques

To be “up for it” is to be ready to face a certain situation. How can I say it in French with the same emotion?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Selon le contexte, dans une situation sérieuse on peut employer :

> Tu t'en sens capable ?

ou de façon plus légère :

> Es-tu prêt(e) à relever le défi ?

Answer (score 11):

There is also *Je suis partant* which suits the previous example:

Who wants to go to the pub? / Qui veut aller au pub?
I'm up for it! / Je suis partant!

Answer (score 5):

*Are you up for it?* could also often be translated as:

> Est-ce que ça te dit ?

Depending on the context, it could also be:

> Est-ce que ça te tente ?

Comment: Yes, and so on the same basis but for the short form, "Up for it?" would nicely correspond to "Ça te dit ?".

Answer (score 3):

If the challenge referred to in this expression is collectively faced, like if the person asking “Are you up for it?” is also part of the action, these are also valid (and heavily used in casual context, by the way):

> T'es dans le coup ?
>   T'es de la partie ?

The example “Who wants to go to the pub? Up for it?” is an excellent example where it could be used.

Comment: And in order to keep the shortness of the original english expression, we can add a third one, slightly less used but belonging to the same register : "T'en es ?" (For which the expected positive answer is "J'en suis !")

Answer (score 3):

Selon le contexte, cela pourrait se traduire aussi par: "Tu te sens d'attaque?"

Answer (score 1):

*Correction suite à la confusion avec [(make) up for it](http://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/search?source=auto&query=up%20for%20it) (compenser)*
[L'expression anglaise](http://www.english-test.net/forum/ftopic14372.html) pour ***I'm*** certainly **up for** it :

> ***I'm*** certainly **willing to** try it.
>   - je suis certainement enclin/disposé à l'essayer.
>   - je suis certainement prêt à tenter le coup.